# How to get the remote device Ipaddress, host name etc for a local only hotspot in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, hotspot, tethering

In **Android 12**, which API or methodology should we use, in order to get the IP address, hostname, MAC address of a remote device that is connected to our hotspot which is of local only hotspot type. Typically,
for a **tethered hotspot**, we could get these information from *wifimanager* and *tethering manager*, but for **local only hotspot** which is created by default for **car projection service**, these information from WiFi manager or tethering manager
is not updated to application.
Please help in knowing how to retrieve the information of the remote device host name, ip address and MAC address when we the access point type is of local only hotspot in android 12
Any leads here wild be of great help ..
thanks in advance!